ReadAfterEOFException при запуске проекта Kotlin Multiplatform на JVM
Я пытаюсь запустить свой проект Kotlin Multiplatform на JVM. Но когда программа вызывает readln(), она вылетает:
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.io.ReadAfterEOFException: EOF has already been reached
    at kotlin.io.ConsoleKt.readln(Console.kt:152)
    at ru.morozovit.dncryptor101.MainKt.main(Main.kt:32)
    at ru.morozovit.dncryptor101.MainKt.main(Main.kt)

Я видел это решение, но оно для обычного Kotlin-проекта. Есть ли аналогичное решение для Kotlin Multiplatform?

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "2.1.0"
    id("com.google.osdetector") version "1.7.3"
}

group = "ru.morozovit"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    js().browser()
    linuxX64()
    linuxArm64()

    sourceSets {
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // As JavaFX have platform-specific dependencies, we need to add them manually
                val fxSuffix = when (osdetector.classifier) {
                    "linux-x86_64" -> "linux"
                    "linux-aarch_64" -> "linux-aarch64"
                    "windows-x86_64" -> "win"
                    "osx-x86_64" -> "mac"
                    "osx-aarch_64" -> "mac-aarch64"
                    else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown OS: ${osdetector.classifier}")
                }

                // Replace "compileOnly" with "implementation" for a non-library project
                implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-base:18.0.2:${fxSuffix}")
                implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:18.0.2:${fxSuffix}")
                implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-controls:18.0.2:${fxSuffix}")
            }
        }
    }
}

settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "dncryptor101"

Main.kt
package ru.morozovit.dncryptor101

import ru.morozovit.dncryptor101.base.Solver
import ru.morozovit.dncryptor101.base.Solver.Companion.ALPHABET_RUSSIAN

import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

fun main() {
    val version = "1.2"
    val solver = Solver()
    println(
        """
            Dncryptor101 
            Version $version
            ------------------ 
        """.trimIndent()
    )
    while (true) {
        print(
            """
                |Select an option:
                |0. Exit
                |1. Decrypt text
                |2. Encrypt text
                |3. About${if (!isNative) "\n4. Enter GUI" else ""}
                |Type a number: 
            """.trimMargin()
        )
        val choice: Int
        try {
            choice = readln().toInt() // вот здесь
        } catch (_: NumberFormatException) {
            println("Try again.")
            continue
        }
        when (choice) {
            0 -> break
            1 -> {
                print("Enter a word to decrypt: ")
                val inp = readln()
                print("Shift (0/Enter if you don't know (list all variants)): ")
                var shift: Int
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        val inp1 = readln()
                        shift = if (inp1 == "") 0 else inp1.toInt()
                        break
                    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                        println("Your input is not a number. Try again.")
                        continue
                    }
                }
                if (shift != 0) {
                    val word = solver.decrypt(inp, shift)
                    println("Your decrypted word: $word")
                    break
                }
                println("\nPossible variants:")
                val words = solver.decrypt(inp)
                var col = 1
                for (word in words) {
                    print(word)
                    col++
                    if (col == 3 + 1 || word.length >= 20) {
                        col = 1
                        println()
                    } else {
                        print(" ")
                    }
                }
                break
            }
            2 -> {
                print("Type a word to encrypt: ")
                val inp = readln()
                print("Shift (0 to generate a random one): ")
                var shift: Int

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        shift = readln().toInt()
                        break
                    } catch (_: NumberFormatException) {
                        println("Your input is not a number. Try again.")
                        continue
                    }
                }
                if (shift == 0) {
                    shift = Random.nextInt(
                        -ALPHABET_RUSSIAN.length..ALPHABET_RUSSIAN.length
                    )
                    println("Your shift: $shift")
                }
                val word = solver.encrypt(inp, shift)
                println("Your encrypted word: $word")

                break
            }
            3 -> {
                println(
                    """
                        
                        A simple program to encrypt and decrypt text.
                        Version $version
                    """.trimIndent()
                )
                break
            }
            4 -> {
                if (isNative) {
                    println("GUI is available only for Java.")
                    break
                }
                launchGUI()
                break
            }
            else -> {
                println("Unknown choice.")
            }
        }
    }
}

Кстати, когда я выполняю gradlew --info runJvm, копирую команду, через которую Gradle запускает мою программу и запускаю ее, ошибка исчезает.

А чем ваш Gradle отличается от Gradle в "том решении"? Ничем. Если у вас падает при запуске из Gradle конечно, это из вопроса однозначно не понятно.
